# I am in "Owner" group of sharepoint site but not able to edit/delete list

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-list

I am in "Owner" group of sharepoint site
By mistake I deleted owner group from "Manage Access" window of a particular list. Hence, though I am owner of site, I am not able to edit/delete list.

Please suggest how to tackle tis condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask your Site Administrator to reinstate the Manage Access.